# Are there any sample Spring MVC + EJB + Maven projects out there that build an EAR?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, spring-mvc, ear

I've already found org.jboss.spring.archetypes:spring-mvc-webapp, but that is structured as a single WAR deployment.

Are there any example (or real OSS) projects out there showing how to structure a EAR project combining EJB jar(s) and a WAR with SpringMVC and maven?

I hacked something together using the previously-mentioned archetype as a starting-point, but it's hopelessly confused IntelliJ's maven integration due to weird dependency problems, so I can only build from the command line - I imagine there must be a better way.